# tomcat-jdbc Datasource PoolProperties configuration

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, datasource, connection-pooling

I am using tomcat-jdbc to connect database. I am Using the following PoolProperties
`p.setUrl(url);
        p.setDriverClassName(dirverClassName);//"mysqlDriver"
        p.setUsername(userName);
        p.setPassword(passWord);
        p.setJmxEnabled(true);
        p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
        p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        p.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);//"select 1"
        p.setTestOnReturn(false);
        p.setValidationInterval(30000);
        p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
        p.setMaxActive(8);
        p.setInitialSize(1);
        p.setMaxWait(1000*60*1);
        p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(2000);
        p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
        p.setMinIdle(1);
        p.setMaxIdle(2);
        p.setLogAbandoned(true);
        p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);`

I have two problems

1>I  getting connections from Data-source frequently. some times it exceeds maxActive. In the same time some connection in DB is in sleep mode. The sleeping connections are closed after **MinEvictableIdleTimeMillis**. so I am getting the following error

```
`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"`
```

2> Some times I need to keep the connections long time, because I am inserting bulge data at one instance. So I am setting large value for MinEvictableIdleTimeMillis. Setting **MinEvictableIdleTimeMillis** time greater is increasing the connection sleep time.

I thing I am using the properties wrongly. Please help me to solve the problems. Kindly guide me to configure the data source properly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1)  The first problem looks like you have met the maximum number of connections available in your server.  I don't actually know how it has happened (check your `max_connections` MySQL variable just in case).  Are you sure you are getting all your connections from the connection pool?  Maybe you are getting some connection in your java code that is not coming from your connection pool (since it should have it in check).  Make sure too that you are returning every `ResultSet`, `Statement` and `Connection` you use (call the `close()` method inside a `finally` block for all those objects once you are done with them)

2) I am not sure why you would keep a database connection idle for 30 seconds in a web application; that could lead you to starvation if you kept 'occupied' your connections that much time.  Please reconsider if that is truly necessary or if you could redesign whatever you are doing in order to make a less restrictive use of database connections

Comment: I am using spring jdbc to handle connections. data source closing the connections properly after MinEvictableIdleTimeMillis.